# Is there any way to remove or somehow avoid line breaks in alpine mail client

Tags: ubuntu, email, gmail, alpine-mail

So i have this really old machine from which i have to send a table(manually) with more than 76 characters in each line.
Alpine does not allow it to be more than 76 and makes a new line

[this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6z6P.png)

looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCpU.png) in cmd

Although alpine itself interprets these like breaks well, ([sent mail looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98UMH.png))

In google mail it is [absolutely broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhJQ9.png)

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Would really appreciate some help on this since i've never really used pine, and tinkering with settings didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The variable "Composer Wrap Column" control the width length. However it is stated that

```
"The largest allowed setting is normally "80" in order to prevent very long
lines from being sent in outgoing mail."
```

But it accepts values larger value than 80 (I tested it with large values and looking at the sent-box, the lengths were effectively corresponded to the large values).

The problem comes from the email provider in question. According to https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text

```
The 78 characters per line is not a limitation implemented by Google, but rather an internet standard for plain text messages (RFC 2822) recommended and promoted by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF).
```

However, if you check your gmail with Alpine as well, the lines are not broken.